# Що означає слово "допіру"?

Tags: значення-слів

Сьогодні почули від незнайомця такий вираз як "зробив це допіру". Що означає слово "допіру"?

Comment: Чи пробували Ви самостійно шукати це слово в словниках?

Comment: @Sasha я вже писав коментарі, щось не надто відгукується пані. Будемо видаляти тоді питання.

Comment: Тоді це питання хай ще буде, а якщо усі наступні будуть без використання джерел, тоді видаляйте.

Comment: @ОксанкаСтрус то вже на розсуд модераторів тепер. Вам на втіху поки проголосую за відповідь))

Comment: ну так, дякую і на тому!)

Comment: @P.Vovk, згоден, що доведеться закривати, але не згоден стосовно видалення: у нас є досить потужна опозиція, чия точка зору полягає у тому, щоб рятувати подібні запитання. Окрім того, важливо, щоб коментарі стосувалися допису, а не авторки. Обговорення користувачів — це порушення принципу **be nice**.

Comment: @P.Vovk А стосовно проблеми низькоякісних дописів у цілому, пропоную підійти до цього фундаментально, а саме — узгодити **Custom Offtopic Reason** і закривати з ним. Ось, наприклад, [мій варіант](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/223/8) (досить сирий, бажано його уточнювати).

Comment: @bytebuster мені подобаються ваші пропозиції, не всі вони сирі, до речі.

Comment: @bytebuster, насправді за політиками Stack Exchange [запитання без reseach effort не мають закриватися, лише мінусуватися](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/308306).

Comment: @Sasha, вірно, а як щодо запитань без контексту? Що означає словосполучення «зробив це допіру»? Якби автор (чи хтось інший — натяк) доклав зусиль до виправлення запитання, воно було б обґрунтовано перевідкрите.

Comment: @bytebuster, якщо відсутність контексту робить відповідь на запитання справді неможливою — то це справді «unclear what you're asking».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сучасний [Словник української мови](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=24040&page=809) подає таку статтю:

> **ДОПІ́РУ**, розм.1. присл.
>
> Тільки що, щойно. Де був допіру, – Ларько вже забув, та й навіщо йому теє знати: де був – нема тепер (С. Васильченко);
>
> Великий глобус Землі без угаву крутиться в нестримному русі між світами. І кожну мить ми вже не там, де були допіру (Б. Антоненко-Давидович);
>
> Вишата розгублено блимав, і Богданові стало смішно, бо той нічого не відав про розмову, що відбулася допіру в світлиці(І. Білик);
>
> Тужливе калатання дзвона летіло у темну ніч, дзвін плакав над нещастям, котре навідало Чишки. Допіру вранці дзвін замовк (Ю. Винничук).
>
> 2. спол.Тільки.
>
> І тьмою тьмиться образ України, допіру він розтане – й я помру (В. Стус);
>
> Він помер, допіру почали збивати обручі [з діжки з вином],від розриву серця, – так хвилювався ласий дідок (Л. Кононович, пер. з тв. О. Гріна).

Отже, таке слово не суржик та існує в українській мові як розмовне.